# Cannot invoke initializer for type 'AVCaptureDeviceInput' with an argument list of type '(device: AVCaptureDevice!, error: inout NSError?)'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am following this from code in an old swift tutorial so possibly there was a change I was unaware of in Swift 2 with how to handle errors, but here is my code

```
backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

var error : NSError?
var input = AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera, error: &error)
```

I do not understand as to why the error in the title even occurs, it occurs highlighting the input variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is deprecated. Use this:

```
var input = AVCaptureDeviceInput()
do {
    input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(backCamera)
} catch {
    //error
}
```

Comment: I think it skipped "deprecated" and went straight to "obsolete".  :)

Answer (score 1):

Check some Swift 2 documentation.  The constructor is defined with a single `device:` parameter and a `throws` annotation instead of the `error:`.

Answer (score 1):

**Update swift3** 
This is how we can handle AVCaptureDeviceInput error on swift3

```
        var input = AVCaptureDeviceInput()
        do {
              input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
           }
        catch {
              //  error
           }
```